# "Invalid digit, Value '.', Pos 0, Type: Integer" while importing pipe delimited file into Redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am importing a pipe-delimited file from an S3 bucket into Redshift using the COPY command.

I am getting this error: `Invalid digit, Value '.', Pos 0, Type: Integer`

When I query stl_load_errors I notice that the line_text and field_text fields are as follows:

line_text: `..1`

field_text: `..1.`

This makes no sense because this is the line in the file:

`1|zzDo not use-P|P`

I have looked at the file in notepad++ to show all the characters and I don't see anything odd. I am really confused as to why Redshift is reading this file all wrong.

EDIT: I am using BCP to output the data from a SQL Server table to the pipe delimited file if that matters

Comment: I suspect you are dealing with a text encoding issue.   You are coming from SQL server so non-UTF-8 encodings (UTF16) are possible (likely) - have you checked the encoding of the file?  (Those dots look to represent characters that could not be parsed).  There is an option to BCP to output in UTF-8 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/184641/using-bcp-export-in-utf-8-format.html

Comment: @BillWeiner thanks for your suggestion. I will try outputting in UTF-8

Comment: The file is currently encoded as UTF-16 LE

Comment: Redshift only reads multi-byte UTF-8.  UTF-16 encodings are seen as 2 characters and the first one (and possibly the second one) make no sense.  Outputting in UTF-8 should fix this.  However, you *MAY* run into a second issue - the end-of-record.  MS tools like to end lines with CR *AND* LF while unix/linux tools like just CR.  You may get some LF characters in your fields so you will want to check your data after loading.  This may not be an issue for you but I'd hate to see you get tripped up by another common MS to Redshift issue.

Comment: @BillWeiner thanks for the tip, I will watch out for that

Comment: @BillWeiner I was able to export to UTF-8 encoding and Redshift liked it. Thank you so much for your help! If you make an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are dealing with a text encoding issue. You are coming from SQL server so non-UTF-8 encodings (UTF16) are possible (likely) - have you checked the encoding of the file? (Those dots look to represent characters that could not be parsed). There is an option to BCP to output in UTF-8.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/184641/using-bcp-export-in-utf-8-format.html

Redshift only reads multi-byte UTF-8. UTF-16 encodings are seen as 2 characters and the first one (and possibly the second one) make no sense. Outputting in UTF-8 should fix this.

However, you MAY run into a second issue - the end-of-record. MS tools like to end lines with CR AND LF while unix/linux tools like just CR. You may get some LF characters in your fields so you will want to check your data after loading. This may not be an issue for you but I'd hate to see you get tripped up by another common MS to Redshift issue.